# Swift 2 phase initialization safety check 4

Tags: ios, swift

As specified in the [Language Guide - Initialization](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Initialization.html), Swift 2 two-phase class initialization involves 4 safety checks. The 4th one reads as follows

> An initializer cannot call any instance methods, read the values of
>   any instance properties, or refer to self as a value **until after the
>   first phase of initialization is complete**.

Where completion of the first phase is described as

> Class initialization in Swift is a two-phase process. *In the first
>   phase, each stored property is assigned an initial value by the class
>   that introduced it. Once **the initial state for every stored property
>   has been determined**, the second phase begins ...*

Now, consider the following example:

```
class A {
    var a: Int
    init() {
        a = 2
    }
}

class B: A {
    var b: Int
    override init() {
        self.b = 8 // (thanks @vadian)
        //First Case: OK
        var b = self.b
        b += 1

        //Second Case: error
        var ab = self.a
        ab += 1

        super.init()
    }
}
```

The second case yields an expected compile time error

> Use of self in property access a before super.init which makes sense
>   because a is not initialized.

But the first case, however, is valid. According to safety check 4 it shouldn't be valid as we use self *before the first phase completes*.

What is the conclusion here. Is the safety check 4, as described in the language guide, not entirely correct?

Comment: I took the liberty of clarifying the intent of your question (which I find interesting), I hope you don't mind. To me, it would seem as if the language docs are possibly a bit vague in their free-text description of phase 1 completion (the Swift language guide is known to include such vagueries at a few locations).

Comment: Not at all. Goal is to clarify. You are helping to achieve the goal.

Answer (score 1):

First of all you have to assign 8 to `self.b` because the compiler treats `b` as local variable – which is declare one line later – throwing this error

> use of local variable 'b' before its declaration

The rule is

- first initialize all instance variables of the (sub)class
- call `super` to initialize the other instance variables of the base class
- use `self`

So class B is supposed to be

```
class B: A {
  var b: Int

  override init() {

    self.b = 8
    //First Case
    var b = self.b

    b += 1

    super.init()

    //Second Case
    var ab = self.a
    ab += 1
  }

}
```

I guess the compiler does something like this under the hood

```
let tmp = 8
self.b = tmp
//First Case
var b = tmp
```

Comment: Disregarding the minor error (`self.b = 8`), I think the OP is concerned with why we're allowed to use `self.b` (in assignment to local variable `b`) prior to fully completing the first phase of initialization: initializing all instance variables. The subclassing in OP:s example really only confuses the root question though: we see the same allowed first case but disallowed 2nd case if just letting class `B` stand on its own with two instance variables `a` and `b` (and using `self.b` prior to initializing `self.a`, which is OK by compiler but somewhat confusing w.r.t. phase 1 completion rule).

Comment: As far as rule is concerned `refer to self as a value until after the first phase of initialization is complete`. Which is not the actual case. We are referring self here before the first phase initialization completes. `var b = self.b`

Comment: I think in this case it's practically not reading the value from the instance variable since the value `8` is introduced in the same scope.

Comment: @vadian I don't see, however, how that could explain [the following example (gist)](https://gist.github.com/dfrib/0079a8d7f751a93d569a) though. Possibly the first-phase of initialization can be separate for each stored property (on their own?) E.g., in my gist example, `self.foo` completes first phase prior to the 2nd stored property `notYetInialized`, and hence the prior may be utilized as if "property-locally" entering phase 2?